# can't open sqlite file in assets folder to copy to device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, android-assets

This is my first application on `Android`. I saw a few questions on this matter, but none had the solution for me.

I have a database in assets folder, named fmdb.sqlite. I used a code example from this link:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

When I get to the line that should get a stream to the sqlite file in the assets folder (copyDataBase method), I get an exception "java.io.FileNotFoundException : fmdb.sqlite".

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Here is my class.

```
public class DatabaseOpener extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
public static String DB_PATH;

public static String DB_NAME = "fmdb.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;



public DatabaseOpener(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    myContext = context; 
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exists to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
   private boolean checkDataBase(){

       SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

       try{
       String myPath = DB_PATH;
       checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

       }catch(SQLiteException e){

       //database does't exist yet.

       }

       if(checkDB != null){

       checkDB.close();

   }

   return checkDB != null ? true : false;
   }

   /**
    * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
    * */
  public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

      boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

      if(dbExist){
          //do nothing - database already exist
          }else{

          //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
          //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
          this.getReadableDatabase();

          try {

          copyDataBase();

          } catch (IOException e) {

          throw new Error("Error copying database");

          }
      }

  }

  /**
   * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
   * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
   * This is done by transfering bytestream.
   * */
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

     //Open your local db as the input stream
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

     // Path to the just created empty db
     String outFileName = DB_PATH;

     //Open the empty db as the output stream
     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
     myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }

     //Close the streams
     myOutput.flush();
     myOutput.close();
     myInput.close();

 }

 public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH;// + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    return myDataBase;
}

 @Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
    myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

**Edit 2**
Here is the LogCat. I uninstalled and rerun the program. now it's about opening the db file for writing, I really appreciate your help!

```
09-29 17:59:19.540: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): copying database from assets... 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): Couldn't open fmdb.sqlite for writing (will try read-only): 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/fmdb.sqlite file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.friendlymeter.dal.MyDatabase.getSample(MyDatabase.java:27) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.friendlymeter.app.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:105) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 09-29 17:59:19.689: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27063): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-29 17:59:19.709: E/SQLiteLog(27063): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4] 09-29 17:59:19.709: E/SQLiteLog(27063): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/com.friendlymeter.app/databases/fmdb.sqlite) - 09-29 17:59:19.909: D/dalvikvm(27063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 130K, 9% free 2652K/2904K, paused 9ms+15ms, total 171ms 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.friendlymeter.app/databases/fmdb.sqlite'. 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at com.friendlymeter.dal.MyDatabase.getSample(MyDatabase.java:27) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at com.friendlymeter.app.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:105) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 09-29 17:59:20.019: E/SQLiteDatabase(27063): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for packaging a database as an asset.

Comment: DB_PATH is always empty. How should this code work?

Comment: @greenapps there is a static section inside the class that initializes DB_PATH (not included in the code, but it's there...)

Answer (score 3):

I agree 100% with CommonsWare's comment. The easiest way to do this is by using the [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). I will post this as an answer but this is 100% copy pasted from the link above. It's all you need to know in order to use this library.

SQLiteAssetHelper is intended as a drop in alternative for the framework's SQLiteOpenHelper. Please familiarize yourself with the behaviour and lifecycle of that class.

Extend SQLiteAssetHelper as you would normally do SQLiteOpenHelper, providing the constructor with a database name and version number:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "northwind.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

SQLiteAssetHelper relies upon asset file and folder naming conventions. Your assets folder will either be under your project root, or under src/main if you are using the default gradle project structure. At minimum, you must provide the following:

A databases folder inside assets
A SQLite database inside the databases folder whose file name matches the database name you provide in code (including the file extension, if any)
For the example above, the project would contain the following:

assets/databases/northwind.db
Earlier versions of this library required the database asset to be compressed within a ZIP archive. This is no longer a requirement, but is still supported. Applications still targeting Gingerbread (API 10) or lower should continue to provide a compressed archive to ensure large database files are not corrupted during the packaging process. The more Linux friendly GZIP format is also supported. The naming conventions using the above example are as follows:

ZIP: assets/databases/northwind.db.zip (a single SQLite database file must be the only file within the archive)
GZIP: assets/databases/northwind.db.gz
The database will be extracted from the assets and copied into place within your application's private data directory. If you prefer to store the database file somewhere else (such as external storage) you can use the alternate constructor to specify a storage path. You must ensure that this path is available and writable whenever your application needs to access the database.

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

The database is made available for use the first time either getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase() is called.

The class will throw a SQLiteAssetHelperException if you do not provide the appropriately named file.

The SQLiteOpenHelper methods onConfigure, onCreate and onDowngrade are not supported by this implementation and have been declared final.

**Edit**

Help requested, and now given. First of all you ***must*** put a `databases` folder inside the `assets` folder. It must be named `databases`, **spelled exactly and case sensitive**. That's where the library looks for your database. Next you ***must*** put the `sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar` inside your `libs` folder. Now just write the code.

Here is some sample code of this in action.

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "your_database_name.sqlite"; // must have file extension
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String SAMPLE_TABLE = "your_table_name";

    public static final String SAMPLE_COLUMN= "your_column_name";

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a sample string.
     * @return sample - a sample string from your database table
     */
    public String getSample() {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columnsArray = { SAMPLE_COLUMN };
        Cursor cursor = database.query(true, SAMPLE_TABLE, columnsArray, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        String sample = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SAMPLE_COLUMN));

        cursor.close();
        database.close();

        return sample;
    }
}
```

Then you call it in your app like this

```
public void databaseTest() {
    MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(YourActivity.this);
    String sample = db.getSample();
    Log.v("SAMPLE", sample);
    db.close();
}
```

If you need anything else let me know

Comment: I have created a class that extends SQLiteAssetHelper, and added a method to create the db in the data/data/.../databases folder. here it is:

public void testCreation()
    {
     SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    }

but when called - I get an exception:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

I tried to put the database file directly in assets folder and then on assets/databases folder - still no luck. Help?...

Comment: I copied this and put the relevant table name and column, and now get a different error (hurray?):
'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database'
I am googling it now - my database is opening in sqlite browser so it's not currupted.

Comment: @amazingwolf Three things. One, make sure your database is in the databases folder. Two, completely uninstall your app from your emulator and/or device. Then run your program again. Three, update your code at the top with your logcat message so that I can see the new code

Comment: Actually now I get a different error, I posted the logcat as an edit in the question... I am new at this, thanks a lot for your patience. If you can help that would be great, I am googling this and all I found were references regarding missing db file extension, which is not the case in my code.

Comment: @amazingwolf 2 things, 1 accept the original answer, 2 ask a new question as the original question has been solved. It helps everyone that comes to this site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK - I finally got it to work with the code I posted Originally. The solution did not require using  SQLiteAssetHelper (although it really reduces the amount of code that has to be written - thanks @javascript for your GREAT HELP). I took an old sqlite db I had and run the app with it - it threw no exceptions when reading it. Although my original file had opened in all sqlite management tools (so no corruption), I decided to create a new database file.

The difference between the old database I used to test the code and the application database was (except for schema) the file extension. The old database extension was ".db", and the app database was ".sqlite". So I created a new database WITH THE ".db" EXTENSION, created all tables in it and - voila - the app succeeds to copy the file from the assets folder to the databases folder in the emulator.

Hope this helps someone, this was been really frustrating :)